# Load and use fixture in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, fixtures, irb

I wonder if there's a way to load and/or use fixture in rails console. Actually, I'd like to create a user from my fixture `users.yml` to do some testing without having to go through all the "pain" of doing `User.new(:name = "John", :email = "..")` each time.
I am currently in test environment (`rails c RAILS_ENV=test`).

If it's not a good way to do things, please say it. I'm new to Rails so I'm here to learn :)

Answer (score 56):

You should be able to load your fixtures prior to entering console. Like this:

```
RAILS_ENV=test bin/rails db:fixtures:load
RAILS_ENV=test bin/rails console
```

However, you still won't be able to access your fixture data like you would in a test. This simply loads your test database with your fixtures data. So you'd still have to do something like:

```
user = User.find_by(name: "John")
```

But, you can still create shortcuts for this sort of thing. You can add any ruby code you'd like to your ~/.irbrc. I suggest creating a .railsrc file as described [here](http://ozmm.org/posts/railsrc.html). You can then set up things like:

```
john = User.find_by(name: "John")
```

So now you can just start referring to the variable 'john' after console loads. Incidentally, the post I linked to shows how to set up a global .railsrc file, but you could set it up so that you had a per project .railsrc. Or, if you want something a little less fancy, but easy to do... just create a ruby file in your project (maybe 'shortcuts.rb'). After console is loaded, just do a require 'shortcuts'.

Comment: Thanks for that answer - however (in Rails 3.2.5, at least) the command is: rails c test

Comment: As of Rails 6.0, `rails c test` does not seem to work. Do instead `RAILS_ENV=test rails c`

Comment: @MasaSakano LOL... back to my original answer 

Answer (score 40):

May be late...
Rails 4

```
require 'active_record/fixtures'
ActiveRecord::FixtureSet.create_fixtures(Rails.root.join('test', 'fixtures'), 'users')
```

Answer (score 18):

You can load fixtures into your development database too:

```
$ rake db:fixtures:load
$ rails c
> require 'active_record/fixtures'
> john = User.find ActiveRecord::FixtureSet.identify('john')
```

Answer (score 7):

So I had a similar but slightly different need. I wanted to use my existing fixtures (from my rspec test) to populate my development database. This is how I did it by adding a new task to my rake file (located in libs/tasks/*.rake):

```
task d_populate: :environment do
  require 'active_record/fixtures'
  fixtures_dir = File.join(Rails.root, '/spec/fixtures') #change '/spec/fixtures' to match your fixtures location
  Dir.glob(File.join(fixtures_dir,'*.yml')).each do |file|
  base_name = File.basename(file, '.*')
  puts "Loading #{base_name}..."
  ActiveRecord::Fixtures.create_fixtures(fixtures_dir, base_name)
  end
end
```

If you combine this with a db:reset you can populate your development environment at will by adding this to your rake task as well:

```
task reseed: [:environment, 'db:reset', 'db:d_populate']
```

Then you can call rake db:reseed to populate from fixture YAML files.

Answer (score 7):

It's possible to specify an alternate fixture directory using the FIXTURES_DIR variable. The value should be relative to test/fixtures.

```
$ rake db:fixtures:load RAILS_ENV=test FIXTURES_DIR='../../spec/fixtures'
```

It's also possible to specify a limited set of fixtures

```
$ rake db:fixtures:load RAILS_ENV=test FIXTURES_DIR='../../spec/fixtures' FIXTURES=users,user_roles
```

Comment: hmm ... that didn't work for me, but this does: rake db:fixtures:load RAILS_ENV=test FIXTURES_PATH='spec/fixtures' FIXTURES=users,participants

Comment: This is the most up to date way to do it as of Rails 6.
`FIXTURES_DIR` may be used to specify a sub directory of test/fixtures.
`FIXTURES_PATH` may be used to specify any path.

Answer (score 6):

You can load a fixture in the Rails 3.2 console as follows:

```
require 'active_record/fixtures'

ActiveRecord::Fixtures.create_fixtures FIXTURE_PATH_HERE, MODEL_NAME_HERE
```